# In Redmine is it possible to have a custom field of type "sortable?

Tags: redmine

in Redmine -> Administration -> Issue Statuses you have the Sort field that allows you to sort elements of the list.

Is it possible to have a custom field with this kind of functionality to we can order the priority of the User Stories without using numbers? (you have to keep spaces between the numbers so you can insert things in the middle, etc) ...

Something like this:

[image]